# javascript regex match single or range

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match with regex (javascript) below two cases:

- pattern case 1: any letter colon any 1 or 2 digits (i.e. A:1)
- pattern case 2: any letter colon any 1 or 2 digits dash any letter:any 1 or
  2 digits (i.e. A:1-A:12)

I tried: ^([A-Z]{1}:(\d+)) which matches only first case

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. It restricts the possible number of digits after the letter (1 or 2) and it also covers the second case:

```
^[A-Z]:\d{1,2}(-[A-Z]:(\d{1,2}))?$
```

Comment: This will also match `A:5A` as there is no `$`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex t make 2nd part an optional match:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]:\d{1,2}(?:-[a-zA-Z]:\d{1,2})?$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2P82w3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Uses Positive lookahead = `(?=...)`

```
^([A-Z]{1}\:\d{1,2}(\-(?=[A-Z]{1}:\d{1,2}))?)+$
```

[Regex Online](https://regex101.com/r/sDk29a/2)